# When grouping on a column (or set of columns) A, how to get the most common value of a column (or set of columns) B in each group of A?

Tags: mysql, sql, join, inner-join, grouping

I am trying to find out how many users were in a building at any given time. For this I have two tables,

Table a

```
Name    ENTER                  EXIT                       COMPANY    Employee
Jack    2013-01-01 01:00:00    2013-01-01 02:00:00        trilogy    Security Guard
Jane    2013-01-01 02:00:00    2013-01-01 03:00:00        trilogy    Security Guard
Judy    2013-01-03 01:00:00    2013-01-04 02:00:00        sindicate  Cleaner
Sam     2013-01-02 05:00:00    2013-01-02 08:00:00        lyop       Engineer
```

To find out how many people are at in the premises I created another table,

Table n

```
a   b
1   2013-01-01 01:00:00
2   2013-01-01 02:00:00
3   2013-01-01 03:00:00
-
-
x   2013-01-05 23:00:00
```

Then I joined them both together to find the total users at any given time using

```
  SELECT DATE(n.b), HOUR(n.b), COUNT(*)
  FROM
  a INNER JOIN n ON n.b BETWEEN a.ENTER
  AND a.EXIT 
  GROUP BY 1, 2
```

Result =

```
Date(n.b)    Hour(n.b)    Count(*)
2013-01-01   1            1
2013-01-01   2            2
2013-01-01   3            1
---
---
2013-01-02   5            1
so on....
```

This works for what I wanted. However now I want to be able to tell the top company(Regardless of Employee type) and top employee (Regardless of company) type occupation of the building per hour too IN ADDTIONAL TO THE UPPER RESULT.

e.g for

```
 Date         Hour  Count(*)     Top-Company  Comp-Count   Top-Employe      Emp-Count 
 2013-01-01   01    1              Trilogy      1          Security Guard    1
 2013-01-01   02    2              Trilogy      2          Security Guard    2
```

I would like to incorporate this into my existing query, if possible. I have very little knowledge of MySQL.

Comment: Are you saying that, for a given date+hour, you want to know the company with the most employees in the building (regardless of type) and the most common employee type in the building (regardless of employer)? Or do you want the most common company-and-employee-type combination in a given date+hour?

Comment: Hi Dave. Yes, Company with most employees regardless of type and most common employee regardless of employer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A general way to do this kind of thing is to build up the complex relations you need from simpler relations. You can treat a query like a table and group it again or join it to a table or another query. Let's do the company first.

This gets you the count of employees in each company in each date+time:

```
select date(n.b) end_date, hour(n.b) end_hour, a.company, count(*) employees_present
from n, a
where n.b between a.enter and a.exit
group by 1, 2, 3;
```

This gets you the largest number of employees that any one company has in each date+time (but loses the company name in the group by):

```
select end_date, end_hour, max(employees_present) max_employees_present
from (
  select date(n.b) end_date, hour(n.b) end_hour, a.company, count(*) employees_present
  from n, a
  where n.b between a.enter and a.exit
  group by 1, 2, 3
) company_counts
group by 1, 2;
```

Join them to get the company name back:

```
select company_counts.end_date, company_counts.end_hour, company_counts.company
from
(
  select date(n.b) end_date, hour(n.b) end_hour, a.company, count(*) employees_present
  from n, a
  where n.b between a.enter and a.exit
  group by 1, 2, 3
) company_counts,
(
  select end_date, end_hour, max(employees_present) max_employees_present
  from (
    select date(n.b) end_date, hour(n.b) end_hour, a.company, count(*) employees_present
    from n, a
    where n.b between a.enter and a.exit
    group by 1, 2, 3
  ) company_counts_2
  group by 1, 2
) max_company_counts
where company_counts.end_date = max_company_counts.end_date and
  company_counts.end_hour = max_company_counts.end_hour and
  company_counts.employees_present = max_company_counts.max_employees_present;
```

After you get through the foregoing you should be able to

- join the entire thing to your original query (which has the total count in each date+time), and
- do it again for employee type.

Comment: sorry for the late response as i had to test it before. Thank you so much, it worked exactly how i wanted it to. Quick question, if I want to have top 3 instead of (max) what changes do I need to make? I can tell somewhere around max(employees_present)

Comment: Glad to hear it worked! To do top three, you could start with the per-hour table of counts (the first query in my answer), join it to itself with a.employees_present >= b.employees present and then group it by the columns in a, having count(*) < 3. Then get the company name back the same way. Needs further thought because more than one company can have the same count in a given hour.

Comment: Yup, I realized, it showed the hour twice whenever two companies have the same count. But thats fine. I'll try the way you mentioned and see how it goes. Once again, thank you so much!